# TypeScript failed to infer the correct type when calling the value of object (which is a function)

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
const record = {
    foo: () => ({ foo: 1 }),
    bar: () => ({ bar: 1 }),
}

function getRecord<T extends keyof typeof record>(type: T) {
    return record[type];
}

const obj = getRecord(`foo`);
// if line 7 is:        return record[type];
// typeof obj will be:  () => { foo: number; }

// but if line 7 is:    return record[type]();
// typeof obj will be:  { foo: number; } | { bar: number; }
obj
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgU1HAJjAvDA3gKBvmAMxBAC4YAKASgwD5KsiTyBGGAXyoBo8CAjAIZxy1OgxiDhMNpx7scOQgFcwwKAEtwMAOYIoAJSQhUAHgAqMBAA8oCMCggwA1ggCeIQjCiuADgg-wRqi0FN5+5GY0uASBUEpwYIHIKADaYQgAutQA3DjyOKCQsCB8AFYYOnqGyRQABsQgtVS5APQtMOqeADbqYAgwAOwdEOQxBIhxCUnGqekZre3pASXlAO7qXV0SCKOi6PSMDeRgSgC2fAhw2RwKbRJKsJ0wPX2Dw6P4E-GJiMlpvpkcjg7ktPCsYOtNttRodmDATudLtd2DAAD7YCRCY5nC5XG4rIA)

When the return value is not called, TypeScript can successfully infer the return type to be `() => { foo: number }`, but when the return value is called, the type inference broadened to `{ foo: number; } | { bar: number; }`. Why is this happening?

Comment: I would suggest making it clearer that you're looking for the reason why it's not inferring the correct type.

Comment: Definitely. I've updated the description.

Comment: if I understand your request, you might want to add the return type explicitly (`ReturnType<typeof record[T]>`), [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgU1HAJjAvDA3gKBvmAMxBAC4YAKASgwD5KsiTyBGGAXyoBo8CAjAIZxy1OgxiDhMNpx7scOQgFcwwKAEtwMAOYIoAJSQhUAHgAqMBAA8oCMCggwA1ggCeIQjCiuADgg-wRqi0FN5+5GZU5IZQSnBgZr4IJmH+nojIKADaZgC69LgEgbHxgZlZqbmiAo4xcQlJKUkBGcbZebQA3DjyOKCQsCB8AFYYOnqGmRQABsQg01TdAPRLMOqeADbqYAgwAOxrEORFBIglYGVtFUm5y6upAUOjAO7qGxsSCMei6AVMZDAwEoALZ8BBwTocBQrCRKWDrGBbHb7Q7HfBneqXVDXPxVRY4GEPTxPGCvd6fY6MObkIGg8GQ9gwAA+2AkQhpILBEKhTyAA)

Comment: Type casting can do the trick, but we want to avoid it as much as possible. Are there any issues about this behavior currently? TypeScript issue tracker is a huge mess and I even can't come up with anything to search with..

Answer (score 2):

The return type of:

```
function getRecord<T extends keyof typeof record>(type: T) {
    return record[type];
}
```

Is `(typeof record)[T]`. As you can see, the generic type parameter influences the return type of the function when function is called.

---

In the second example:

```
function getRecord<T extends keyof typeof record>(type: T) {
    return record[type]();
}
```

The return type is `{ foo: number } | { bar: number }`. Here the generic parameter doesn't affect it (already used to pre-evaluate the return type).